Help in plotting the band structure of a maple leaf lattice
I was trying to plot the band structure of a maple leaf lattice. The Hamiltonian is given by:
$H = t_1 \sum_{ij} (c^\dagger_i c_j + c^\dagger_j c_i e^{\phi_{ij}}) + \sum_{ij} \sum^{4}_{n=2} t_n (c^\dagger_i c_j + c^\dagger_j c_i) $,
Here, I was asked by my professor to set $t_2 = t_3 = t_4 = \phi_{ij} = 0$ and $t_1 = -1$, so the Hamiltonian now is:
$H = -\sum_{ij} (c^\dagger_i c_j + c^\dagger_j c_i)$
How can I proceed from here to plot the band structure? Since the unit cell has 6 atoms, I need six bands in my band structure. I tried to rewrite the sum as a sum over nearest neighbour vectors and then take a Fourier transform of the operators, but that is only giving me one band. I am pretty sure I will have to take different creation and annihilation operators for each unit cell atom, but  I am seemingly getting stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I think you can more easily find how the calculation is done for some simpler non-Bravais lattice like the honeycomb one, and easily adapt that.
